# How to include 2 continuous greek letters in superscript?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The title is exactly the question, I am struggling with different combinations to achieve this  2-ΔΔCt being the "-ΔΔCt" part as superscript

I want to insert it in a plot and this is a fragment of the code within the plot syntax

```
 labs(
    y = "Genes", x = expression(2^-Delta~Delta*Ct),
    title = "Gene expression",
    subtitles = "1 year post-intervention")
```

[image]

Comment: Use a “*” between them.

Comment: What is the actual and the expected output? This isn’t currently clear from your question.

Comment: You just want everything in the exponent? Try `expression(2^{-Delta*Delta*Ct})`

Comment: I suspect the negative sign may need to be flanked be quotes. The tilde the you and others are suggesting will put a full space between the deltas. Your image suggests you want no space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use curly braces to group the superscript together. And you can use `*` instead of `~` if you don't want space between the deltas.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, wt)) +geom_point() +
  labs(
    y = "Genes", x = expression(2^{-Delta*Delta*Ct}),
    title = "Gene expression",
    subtitles = "1 year post-intervention")
```

[image]